# Elastic Search Query with Java Api

Tags: java, api, elasticsearch

I'm developing JSF project and using Elastic Search with native Java Api(not Jest).
I defined analyzer and nGram filter for advanced full text search in elasticsearch index mapping. How can do this Query defination with java api ?

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/blurays/_search?pretty" -d'
{
"size": 10,
"query":{
"match":  {
"_all": {
"query": "yellow bird",
"operator": "and"
        }
          }
       }
}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of your intention, but if you want to create an "and"/"or" queries try something like this:

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
```

and for example:

```
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(field, value));
```

You can add as many queries (any type - multiMatch, term etc.) as you want. Try also try should() or mustNot() methods - depends of what do you want.

Here is a more complex example: 
http://massapi.com/class/bo/BoolQueryBuilder.html

---

EDIT:
Thanks for comment, now I think I'm understand.
Something like below?

```
QueryBuilders.matchQuery(field, value).operator(MatchQueryBuilder.Operator.OR);
```

Comment: Actually I want to do something http://blog.qbox.io/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams this link . I made all analyzer ,ngram ve tokenizer defination. I successed to work this query with curl but I tried a lot of query type in java api and no solution.

Comment: Thanks for reply Tomek.The code in  your edit works fine thanks a lot.  Can you look at this question ? Nobody answered this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765465/elasticsearch-full-text-search